# Can SMOTE be applied over sequence of words (sentences)?

Tags: class-imbalance, text-classification, smote

I have a highly unbalanced text classification data. I am trying to over-sample through SMOTE.

I have a doubt that applying SMOTE over sequence of word indices will give me valid data points or not (since SMOTE used nearest neighbor like method)?

Comment: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/27758/8878