# Imbalanced data causing mis-classification on multiclass dataset

Tags: machine-learning, python, classification, scikit-learn, multiclass-classification

I am working on text classification where I have 39 categories/classes and 8.5 million records. (In future data and categories will increase).

Structure or format of my data is as follows.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| product_title          | Key_value_pairs                               | taxonomy_id |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Samsung S7 Edge        | Color:black,Display Size:5.5 inch,Internal    | 211 
                          Storage:128 GB, RAM:4 GB,Primary Camera:12 MP  

  Case cover Honor 8     | Color:transparent,Height:15 mm,width:22 mm    | 212 

  Ruggers Men's T-Shirt  | Size:L,ideal for:men,fit:regular,             | 111
                          sleeve:half sleeve

  Optimum Nutrition Gold | Flavor:chocolate,form:powder,size:34 gm       | 311
  Standard Whey Protein
```

Data distribution is not normal; it is highly imbalanced:

```
-------------------------
| taxonomy_id |   count |
-------------------------
          111 |  851750 
          112 |  355592
          113 |  379433
          114 |   23138
          115 |  117735
          116 |  145757
          117 | 1339471
          121 |  394026
          122 |  193433
          123 |   78299
          124 |  111962
          131 |    1776
          132 |    4425
          133 |     908
          134 |   23062
          141 |   22713
          142 |   42073
          211 |    7892
          212 | 1574744
          221 |    1047
          222 |  397515
          223 |   53009
          231 |    1227
          232 |    7683
          251 |     739
          252 |     327
          253 |   38974
          254 |      25
          311 |    2901
          321 |    7126
          412 |     856
          421 |  697802
          422 |  414855
          423 |   17750
          425 |    1240
          427 |     658
          429 |    1058
          431 |   20760
          441 |     257
```

As you can see they are highly imbalanced and leading to mis-classifications.

Steps I have performed till now

**1) Merge product_title and key_value_pairs column and remove stop words and special characters and perform stemming.**

**2) I have used pipeline for TFIDFvectorizer(), LinearSVC()**

```
vectorizerPipe = Pipeline([
                 ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer(lowercase=True, stop_words='english')),
                 ('classification', OneVsRestClassifier(LinearSVC(penalty='l2', loss='hinge'))),
                 ])
```

After this I have fit pipeline and stored the classifier in pickle

```
prd = vectorizerPipe.fit(df.loc[:, 'description'], df.loc[:, 'taxonomy_id'])
```

**On Testing side I have repeated step 1 as mentioned above and then load the pickle and use predict function**

```
pd = cl.predict([testData])
```

Issues I am facing

1. A lot of products are being mis-classified into some other categories

   Example: Ultimate Nutrition Prostar 100% Whey Protein should be classified into category 311 but my classifier is classifying it as 222 which is completely wrong.
2. I am not sure whether to use TFidfVectorizer() or Hashingvectorizer(), can you guys help me in selecting one of this along with  their parameters?
3. Algorithm I am using is LinearSVC, is it a good choice for multi-class classification problems with large amount of data? Or should I use different algorithms?
4. As my data is highly imbalanced I tried random undersampling. The results were improved but  they were still not up to the mark.
   Also I am not sure whether this is the right approach to perform random undersampling:

   ```
   pipe = make_pipeline_imb(
       HashingVectorizer(lowercase=True),
       RandomUnderSampler(ratio={111: 405805, 112: 170431, 113: 241709, 114: 8341, 115: 50328, 116: 89445, 117: 650020, 121: 320803, 122: 162557, 123: 66156, 124: 36276, 131: 1196, 132: 3365, 133: 818, 134: 15001, 141: 6145, 142: 31783, 211: 24728, 212: 100000, 221: 791, 222: 8000, 223: 35406, 231: 785, 232: 3000, 251: 477, 252: 127, 253: 29563, 254: 33, 311: 2072, 321: 5370, 412: 652, 421: 520973, 422: 99171, 423: 16786, 425: 730, 427: 198, 429: 1249, 431: 13793, 441: 160},random_state=1), 
       OneVsRestClassifier(LinearSVC(penalty='l2', loss='hinge')))
   ```
5. I am new in machine learning so I have used this approach for text classification. If my approach is wrong then please correct me with right one.

(It would be great if you give suggestion or solution with examples as it will help me understand better).

***EDIT-1****

```
RndmFrst = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, max_depth=20, max_features=5000,n_jobs=-1)
LogReg = LogisticRegression()
voting = VotingClassifier(estimators=[('LogReg ', LogReg), ('RndmFrst', RndmFrst)], voting='soft', n_jobs=-1)

pipe = Pipeline([('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,4), max_features=50000)), ('clf', voting)])

pipe = pipe.fit(df.loc[:,'description'], df.loc[:,'taxonomy_id'])
Preds = pipe.predict(test_data)
```

Comment: I just saw that you tried under-sampling. Just fyi, Startified K-fold cross validation in Sci-Kit Learn also takes class distribution into account.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nice question!

### Some Remarks

For imbalanced data you have different approaches. Most well-established one is [resampling](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/27671/how-do-you-apply-smote-on-text-classification/27758#27758) (Oversampling small classes /underssampling large classes). The other one is to make your classification hierarchical i.e. classify large classes against all others and then classify small classes in second step (classifiers are not supposed to be the same. Try model selection strategies to find the best).

### Practical Answer

I have got acceptable results without resampling the data! So try it but later improve it using resampling methods (statistically they are kind of A MUST).

TFIDF is good for such a problem. Classifiers should be selected through model selection but my experience shows that Logistic Regression and Random Forest work well on this specific problem (however it's just a practical experience).

You may follow the code bellow as it worked simply well then you may try modifying it to improve your results:

```
train = pd.read_csv(...)
test = pd.read_csv(...)    

# TFIDF Bag Of Words Model For Text Curpos. Up to 4-grams and 50k Features
vec = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,4), max_features=50000)
TrainX = vec.fit_transform(train)
TestX = vec.transform(test)


# Initializing Base Estimators
clf1 = LogisticRegression()
clf2 = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, max_depth=20, max_features=5000,n_jobs=-1)

# Soft Voting Classifier For Each Column
clf = VotingClassifier(estimators=[('lr', clf1), ('rf', clf2)], voting='soft', n_jobs=-1)
clf = clf.fit(TrainX, TrainY)
preds = clf.predict_proba(TestX)[:,1]
```

Please note that the code is abstract so TianX, TrainY,TestX,etc should be properly defined by you.

### Hints

Be careful about what is StopWord. Practically many people (including myself!) made this mistake to remove stop words according to pre-defined lists. That is not right!

Stop words are corpus-sensitive so You need to remove stopwords according to information theoretic concepts (to keep it simple you need to know TFIDF kind of ignores your corpus-specific stopwords. If you need more explanation please let me know to update my answer).

VotingClassifier is a meta-learning strategy in the family of [Ensemble Methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_learning). They take benefit from different classifiers. Try them as they work pretty well in practice.

Voting schema simply takes the results of different classifiers and return the output of the one which has the highest probability to be right. So kind of democratic approach against dictatorship ;)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi @KasraManshaei i tried your solution on my small data and it is working fine thanks for you suggestion. 1) can you give a example of how to use voting classifier in pipeline?  Thank you again!

Comment: I am glad it helped! check this for your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46793110/using-votingclassifier-in-sklearn-pipeline