# DBSMOTE on Short Text Classification

Tags: nlp, feature-extraction, tfidf, smote

I am trying to use DBSMOTE(Density-Based Synthetic Oversampling TEqnique) to on a data set of short text--tweets to be specific. This will be used to train a classifier model in a multiclass classification model. This will be done at feature level augmentation, using TF-IDF as features. I have read though, that to use SMOTE on NLP, the feature vectors must be reduced in dimension. What is an optimal size of a feature vector to use in a SMOTE family algorithm?

Similar Question: [How do you apply SMOTE on text classification?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/27671/how-do-you-apply-smote-on-text-classification?rq=1)

DBSMOTE Code: https://rdrr.io/cran/smotefamily/man/DBSMOTE.html

DBSMOTE Paper: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10489-011-0287-y

Comment: Hey! It'd be great if you added a link to where you read that about SMOTE on NLP. That way, we can read further on the topic and try to help you on that.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @jmnavarro, I'm very new to using StackExchange